# Push Notifications in App

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, firebase

Context: Building a marketplace app in which the seller needs to approve the buyer

Is there a way for my server (using Parse until I migrate to AWS) to send an update to a user's app when they have the app open (to let them know they've been accepted by the buyer) without using the full push notification system through Apple? I believe firebase allows this through observing value states, does anyone know if there is a way to do this with parse?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: never used firebase but you could do this (when the app is in foreground) by checking with your server periodically. A push notification would be a better alternative as you can respond to these when the app is in foreground too.

Answer (score 0):

i dug some stuff about notifications and i had good results using https://onesignal.com/

you configure a project there, register your mobile app with them and using their rest api you send notifications quite easily.

manage apn/gcm yourself can work too, however the code needed is unpleasant and if you server needs to provide notifications to more than one platform complexity grows too much.